# Apply a function to each dimension of a 4d array, returning an 4d array in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I load MNIST (test) dataset which is shaped as (10000, 28, 28, 1) (which mean 10000 images (grayscale 28x28 image)). I want to apply motion blur kernel on each of the images and get the output of also the same shape (10000, 28, 28, 1).
I tried with def, vectorize but it doesn't work as I expected.

It's running on python 3.6

```py
x_test.shape
--> (numpy.ndarray) (10000, 28, 28, 1)


def blurize(x):
    # kernel
    k = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0013],
    [0,0,0,0.0086,0.0574,0.1061,0.1165],
    [0,0.0450,0.0938,0.1426,0.0938,0.0450,0],
    [0.1165,0.1061,0.0574,0.0086,0,0,0],
    [0.0013,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
    return (ndimage.convolve(x.reshape(28,28), k, mode='constant', cval=0.0))

blurred = blurize(x_test)
plt.imshow(blurred[1], interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Result:

```py
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 7840000 into shape (28,28)
```

If I tried with 
`blurred = blurize(x_test[1]).` it works but only for the second image. Since I don't want to loop over the whole array by the x_test[i] and merge frames into the expected output array of (10000, 28, 28, 1) again.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) the input array, broadcast the kernel and then reshape the output to match the initial dimensions:

```
ndimage.convolve(x.squeeze(), k[None, ...], mode='constant', cval=0.0)[..., None]
```